# FxCop is confusing on how to eliminate the redundant castclass

Tags: c#, casting, fxcop

I am trying to resolve some fxcop issues and I am really confused about this issue.

In a setter of a derived class, I am checking if assignment should be made

```
if (!(value is TypeA))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("value is not of TypeA type");
}

_action = (TypeA)value;
```

FxCop is complaining:

> 'value', a parameter, is cast to type 'TypeA' multiple times in method. Cache the result of the 'as' operator or direct cast in order to eliminate the redundant castclass instruction.

BUT, in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28VS.90%29.aspx) msdn example (`is` definition ) I see this:

```
if (o is Class1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("o is Class1");
    a = (Class1)o;
}
```

which is exactly the same thing I do. So, is there a resolution for this?

All I can think is:

```
TypeA tmpAction = value as TypeA;
if(tmpAction == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentException();
}

_action = tmpAction;
```

Comment: Yes, what you thought of is correct. What do you feel is wrong with that?

Comment: I am confused whether it's correct since msdn does the same as I do

Comment: There are many examples on MSDN that would not be considered best practice. Some are kept simple on purpose, perhaps by skipping input validation.

Comment: Yes, not everything you see on MSDN conforms with FxCop's recommendations. The first snippet of code is not *wrong* per se, FxCop is just telling you that there's a *better* way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TypeA tmpAction = value as TypeA;
if(tmpAction == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

The example you give is correct - if you need to cast and use a variable with the type you cast to, use `as` and a `null` check instead of `is` so you don't have to do it twice.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution using the `as` operator is what you should do. Note that you can't do it in case `TypeA` is a value type, `as` is only applicable to reference types.